# IE11 HTML5 Video Error

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, video

I've had a look but I can't see a answer for this one.

I'm using the HTML5 video tag on my website which is currently on XAMPP/ Appache. In Firefox it works perfectly but in Chrome it only plays the audio from the video and not the video itself and in IE11 it comes up with the error "Unsupported video type or invalid file path".

I've checked in the developer tools and the browsers appear to be reading the file extension correctly.

I've updated my httpd.conf file with the following...

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

...so it shouldn't be a MIME type issue.

And I've added several file type options as follows:

```
<section id='content_blank'>
        <video controls width=640 height=368 poster='<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/vid.jpg'>
            <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>video/face.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>video/face.webm" type='video/webm'>
            <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>video/face.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
        <p>Sorry! Your web browser does not support HTML5</p>
        </video>
    </section>
```

Which I believe should deal with any incompatibility issues. I even tried converting the files a second time to make sure there was nothing wrong with them... I'm now at a loss.

Anyone out there have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to share links to the videos - this will help isolate the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the content belongs to a client and I don't have permission to distribute it.